# Что обозначает двунаправленная @OneToMany ассоциация в hibernate сессии?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, h2

В [документации](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many) сказано, что информация о связи хранится в виде внешнего ключа в сущности потомка. Объявление двунаправленной связи позволяет на тратится на связующую таблицу.
Я подумал, что `@OneToMany` говорит мапперу пройти по таблице потомка и найти там все строки, у которых внешний ключ(который обозначается в параметре `OneToMany.mappedBy`). Но нет. Оказывается разработчик сам должен позаботиться о синхронизации с обеих сторон. Прописал родителя в таблицу потомка- возьми у родителя список потомков и добавь текущего. Добавил родителю нового потомка- запиши родителя в этого потомка.
В таком случае непонятно что делает `@OneToMany`(что-то делает, ведь если заменить его на `@Transient` о оставить ручную синхронизацию в клиенте то все ломается)

Comment: ссылкой на документацию поделитесь?

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many

Comment: Если у Вас есть в родителе `@OneToMany`, а в потомке `@ManyToOne`, то при обращении к children в родителе, Hibernate смапит все дочерние записи Вам. Это в случае чтения. Плюс не стоит забыть про кэширование и объекты. Если Вы руками выполните запрос БД по добавлению нового потомка, никакой Hibernate (или любой другой ORM) об этом не узнает. А если Вы уже прочитали потомков, то новые туда ну никак не добавятся. А в чем Ваша претензия?

Comment: А двунаправленная ассоциация означет, что родитель знает про всех своих потомков, а каждый потомок знает своего родителя. В случае однонаправленной ассоциации, потомки напрямую не знают о родителе, поэтому Hibernate, по-умолчанию, будет генерить Вам линковочную таблицу, чтобы родитель знал про потомков.